# Trying to use dense rank ,Getting error in ranks using dense rank

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the unique rank for every unique value in `column a`:

```
-------------------
column a  column b 
-------------------
1234.            1
6353.            5
3636.            4 
7266.            6 
2772.            3 
2663.            2
2663.            2
```

I want something like this. But getting higher number of values in `column b` it’s counting extra. Please help me how to ignore any discrepancies while doing this.
As of now I am using this:

```
Dense_rank() over ( order by column a ) as abc
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT 
   ColumnA,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ColumnB
FROM (VALUES
   ('1234'),
   ('6353'),
   ('3636'),
   ('7266'),
   ('2772'),
   ('2663'),
   ('2663')
) v (ColumnA)
```